# Facebook send friend a greeting

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication, facebook-authorization

I'm using fackbook JS API in order to get the user's friends.
The user choose one of his friends in a website and send him a greeting.
The server gets a source facebook ID of the user and a destination facebook ID (from his friends list)

how can I be sure that the user didn't "touch" the source user and destination user facebook ID ?

I want to save it in my database.
is there any solution for that?

BR,
AViad

Comment: What do you want to do with that info? I hope you are aware that you are not allowed to “reward” your users in any way for using Facebook social channels, right?

Comment: No. 
I'm just creating a facebook app and i want to send "coins" frmo user A to user B but i want to be sure that they are friends

Comment: Well then just [ask the API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/#readmodifiers) if the user id you’re getting passed is a friend of the active user …

Comment: I can use js API  but i cannot assure that becase someone can ''hack'' and change the js objects at the client or change the request to save that using fiddler or chrom dev tools. So ehat can i do?

Comment: You can’t be sure of anything that happens on the client. All you can do is add a server-side component and check there if the ids passed to it are actually friends afterwards.

Comment: So you mean to run a javascript on the server? How?

Comment: Doesn’t have to be JavaScript, any server-side technology able to make HTTP requests will do.